# Issue on Getting Geometry of pgRouting Query in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am running this query against a Table `victoria` enabled with pgRouting and PostGIS

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                source::integer,
                target::integer,
                length::double precision AS cost
                FROM victoria',
9411, 3986, false, false);
```

which in result return **269** rows in a table like

[image]

I also need to get geometry multi string of nodes so I tried to achieve them like

```
SELECT route.*, ST_AsText(geom) FROM victoria
JOIN(
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                         SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                         FROM victoria',
                         9411, 3986, false, false)) AS route
ON              
victoria.gid = route.seq;
```

[image]

this returns **268**! rows plus the exactly same result of `geom` for all queries no matter if I change the `9411, 3986` any other number the geometry is always same. can you please let me know how I can get the correct geometry

Update

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the returned `seq` is just a [sequence](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html?highlight=pgr_dijkstra#description-of-the-return-values-for-a-path) ranging from 1 to the number of nodes in the route. It is NOT related to the source data and should not be used in a join. It is however very useful for sorting the route segments.

So, if you want the original segments, you would do the join on the edge ID

```
SELECT route.*, ST_AsText(victoria.geom) 
FROM victoria
JOIN(
SELECT seq, node, edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                         SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                         FROM victoria',
                         9411, 3986, false, false)) AS route
ON              
victoria.gid = route.edge;
```

Comment: Thanks a lots jGH but looks like the query is not returning all linestrings! can you please take a look at the posted image (I just up loaded). As you can see in the image the query always missing some segments

Comment: looks like at least two segments are missing at `Herald St` intersecrion